# C# - how to display metadata about sql tables that are retrieved from another table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-metadata

So, I have a database with 7 tables. One of these tables, lets call it `tablesOfInterest`, simply contains rows of other tables in the database. This table changes regularly.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Retrieve the table names from `tablesOfInterest`.
2. Display metadata about these tables. Specifically, all column names and the number of rows.

I read here [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_GetSchema_System_String_System_String___) about using string[] index to display metadata about specific tables, but when I run my current code I get the error:

> More restrictions were provided than the requested schema [tables]
>   supports.

Where am I going wrong?

Method One:

```
        public static List<string> GetTables() {

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string sqlString;
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            sqlConnection = DBConnection.GetSqlConnection();

            sqlString = "select * from TablesOfInterest";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, sqlConnection);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Error! \n" + e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("General Error! \n" + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return result;


    }
```

Method two:

```
 public static List<string> GetMetaDataTables()
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        String[] restrictions = new String[5];

        try
        {
            con = DBConnection.GetSqlConnection();

            foreach (string s in GetMetaData())
            {
                restrictions[2] = s;
            }

            DataTable schemaTable = con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);

            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                result.Add(row[2].ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sql Error! \n " + e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("General Error! \n " + e);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Update:

I tried Mikes suggestions and that certainly helped! It now displays the names of the tables correctly. It does not however display the amount of rows. To try and achieve that I did this:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = Controller.GetMetaDataTables().Select(x => new { 
Value = x.Value, Name = x.Key }).ToList();
```

In my gridView I only see the table names though, how can I select the no of rows aswell?

Comment: So the first column `reader.GetString(0)` of `TablesOfInterest` is the table name?

Comment: Where is the `GetMetaData()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific error you're getting:

> More restrictions were provided than the requested schema [tables] supports.

is because the `Tables` collection requires `3` restrictions: database, owner and table.

However, the next problem you have is even if `restrictions` was defined as:

```
var restrictions = new string[3];
```

this code would only retrieve the schema for the last table in `TablesOfInterest`:

```
foreach (string s in GetMetaData())
{
    restrictions[2] = s;
}

DataTable schemaTable = con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);

foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
{
    result.Add(row[2].ToString());
}
```

That's because the call to `GetSchema` belongs inside the iteration of the first `for` loop like this:

```
foreach (string s in GetMetaData())
{
    restrictions[2] = s;

    DataTable schemaTable = con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);

    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        result.Add(row[2].ToString());
    }
}
```

The next problem you have is that `result` really needs to be a dictionary:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

because you're recovering column information for multiple tables. That would change that iteration to be something like this:

```
foreach (string s in GetMetaData())
{
    restrictions[2] = s;

    DataTable schemaTable = con.GetSchema("Tables", restrictions);

    result.Add(s, new List<string>());
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        result[s].Add(row[2].ToString());
    }
}
```